# Call a function when inner divs scrolled to top of the containing div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to get a function to fire when the inner divs are scrolled to the top of the containing div. I don't know how many inner divs there will be, so I need it to work with div Classes, not IDs.  I just can't seem to wrap my head around the correct logic for the isScrolledIntoView function.

The function should fire when the title is in the box on top.

You can see a (non)working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/bigredboots/dzm1qrgj/5/

```js
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
  var listem = $('#listem');
  var docViewTop = listem.scrollTop();
  var wh = listem.height();
  var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
  return ((elemTop <= docViewTop));
}

$(function() {
  $('#listem').scroll(function(e) {
    var anchors = $('.section');
    for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; ++i) {
      if (isScrolledIntoView(anchors[i])) {
        var title = $(anchors[i]).data('title');
        $('#top-bar').html(title);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.section {
  min-height: 1000px;
}

#listem {
  height: 600px;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 60px;
  position: relative;
}

.top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: aqua;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
  <div id="top-bar">titles</div>
</div>
<div id="listem">
  <div class="section" data-title="Part one"><span class="title">Section 1</span></div>
  <div class="section" data-title="Part two"><span class="title">Section 2</span></div>
  <div class="section" data-title="Part three"><span class="title">Section 3</span></div>
  <div class="section" data-title="Part four"><span class="title">Section 4</span></div>
  <div class="section" data-title="Part five"><span class="title">Section 5</span></div>
  <div class="section" data-title="armadillo"><span class="title">Section 6</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work as it is in the snippet I made you after I added the jQuery library

Comment: If you add a reference to jQuery to the code it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ensg7tdp/

Comment: Your non-working JSFiddle ALSO needs jQuery added

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan -  but the function should fire "JUST" when the title is in the box, and right now it fires at the wrong time.